# XML deserialization does not work

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I need to deserialize a XML file to a object. The XML contents:

```
  <Players dealerId="2">
    <Player id="1">
      <ScreenName>JetYeo</ScreenName>
    </Player>
    <Player id="2">
      <ScreenName>Test</ScreenName>
    </Player>
  </Players>
```

I define a object class:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Players")]
public class Players
{
    [XmlAttribute("dealerId")]
    public int DealerId { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Player", typeof(Player))]
    public Player[] Players { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Player")]
public class Player
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ScreenName")]
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
}
```

However, deserialization does not work: Players array is null. Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because the attributes are wrong; the difference is that `XmlArrayItem` expects an two-level relationship (`<Players><Players><Player .../>...</Players></Players>`); hence for `Players` it should be:

```
[XmlElement("Player")]
public Player[] Players { get; set; }
```

although personally, I'd prefer:

```
private readonly List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
[XmlElement("Player")]
public List<Player> Players { get { return players; } }
```

(i.e. no `set`, and a list instead of an array)

or even the lazily-instantiated:

```
private List<Player> players;
[XmlElement("Player")]
public List<Player> Players {
    get { return players ?? (players = new List<Player>()); }
}
```

Comment: Note that the list cannot be named `Players` since the type is named the same.

Comment: @alexn well spotted - I was taking that from the question, though

Answer (score 7):

The best way to identify this kind of problems is to actually reverse your serialization logic.
Create the object with the data that matches the data you have in your XML. Then try to serialize it so that the output is the same as the data you would like to deserialize.

This way, you can actually 'see' the effect of the available attributes that you can apply on the properties.

If it serializes the same, you can also deserialize it.